# how to get particular field from the result of full test search in monodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, search, full-text-search

I have some documents in my mongodb as follows

```
{"Filename":"PHP Book.pdf","Author":"John" ,"Description":"This is my PHP Book"} 
{"Filename":"Java Book.html" ,"Author":"Paul" ,"Description":"This is my JAVA Book"}
{"Filename":".NET Book.doc" ,"Author":"James" ,"Description":"This is my .NET Book"}
```

I have created text index on Description field and below is my code which does full text search on Description field.

```
            m = new Mongo("10.0.0.26", 27017);
            DB db = m.getDB("soft") ;
            DBCollection col = db.getCollection("pocnew") ;
            String collection = col.toString();
            DBObject searchCmd = new BasicDBObject();
            searchCmd.put("text", collection);  
            searchCmd.put("search", "php"); 
            CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);
            System.out.println(commandResult);
```

I am getting following result

```
{ "serverUsed" : "/10.0.0.26:27017" , "queryDebugString" : "php||||||" , "language" : "english" , "results" : [ { "score" : 0.5833333333333334 , "obj" : { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51cd7d302d45471420c1132b","Filename":"PHP Book.pdf","Author":"John" ,"Description":"This is my PHP Book"}]}}
```

My requirement is to display only filename field value i.e only `PHP Book.pdf`

please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: System.out.println(commandResult.getString("Description"));

Comment: it is returning null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to dig through the returned document to get to Filename

```
CommandResult commandResult = db.command(searchCmd);
BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList)commandResult.get("results");
for( Iterator< Object > it = results.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
{
    BasicDBObject result  = (BasicDBObject) it.next();
    BasicDBObject dbo = (BasicDBObject) result.get("obj");
    System.out.println(dbo.getString("Filename"));
}
```

In addition, if you just need the Filename field, you may want to add project option in searchCmd to limit the number of fields returned in search results.  See the following link for text command returned document details and project option.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/text/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the code but it is showing null pointer exception at this line "for( Iterator< Object > it = results.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )", can u please help me in solving this...

Comment: Sry i forgot to enable text search, now its working thank you so much.